# Is memory leak possible, when I directly change the char array in std::string by accessing the address of it?

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    char* c =  &s[0];
    c[0] = '4';
    c[1] = '3';
    c[2] = '\0';
    
    cout << s.data();
}
```

You can access the char array inside a string like this. But, I think that it is undefined behavior. This behavior make that many features of the string are not worked.

What I'm wondering is, is there any possible of a memory leak because of this approach?

Comment: why do you expect a memory leak? You arent allocating any memory that could leak

Comment: Since the string is initially empty, this is definitely UB

Comment: you never allocated the memory how can you use it? It UB, so fix UB first then worry about Memory Leak.

Comment: Yes it is undefined behavior, anything is possible. Also a memory leak (although, nothing in the code suggest that there would be one, but anything is possible)

Comment: why do you care specifically about a leak?

Comment: You first need to resize the string to so all access is within the size. Else access to the elements is UB. Though due to small string optimization it is unlikely to cause seg fault.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a memory leak, per se, since there are no dynamic memory allocations that will not be released   However, it does have undefined behaviour since a default-constructed `std::string` has size zero, and your code assumes it has `size()` which is at least 3.

Comment: why are you worried about memory leak, when it is likely to just crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right that it is Undefined Behavior. With Undefined Behavior, anything can happen. That does include "memory leak", which can occur in isolation or in combination with any other symptom.

Of course, "memory leak" isn't that important when the other problems happening are "crash" or "computer on fire". So just add an `s.resize(3)`. That solves the UB.

Comment: In most cases you are right. But that doesn't apply in this case, because string provides a capacity of 16 by default. Also, the increased capacity cannot be reduced using the reserve function. 
In fact, I think that memory leaks will not occur if only reserve is used properly. However, through the comments in my article, I've come to think that it's not right to access strings in an undefined way.

Comment: @3088K: You're assuming the Small String Optimization here. That's not guaranteed. But even if you _have_ checked the `.capacity()`, you're still not allowed to access non-existing members. `capacity` only tells you which `resize`s are cheap.